# Redirect/forward ROS logs to journald

Tags: linux, logging, ros2, systemd-journald

I have a C/C++ application which runs by ROS2 eloquent with different nodes each of which logs some information under `.ros/log`. My question is is there any way to redirect/forward ROS logs to journald service of Linux (so that ros log files under `.ros/log` will be empty or not generated)?